# Implementing Connections within Aggregation classes

Tags: uml, aggregation, class-diagram

In the below diagram, the class "Copy" and class "Book" are showing an aggregation (Book **has a** Copy). All other classes are sub classes of class "Copy". Now, imagine there is a `Member` class, which has to access the sub classes "Lending" and "Borrow" of class "Copy". The only thing that '`Member`' class should know is "accessionNumber".

If we think of this in terms of code, my "`Book`" class contains an array of "`Copy`".

[image]

How can I know the accessionNumber of a particular book?

Lets say I need the "accessionNumber" of the 3rd book in my `copies` array. But the array is in the `Book` class, and there is no connection to the `Book` class from the `Copy` class.

If we create a connection back, would that be like "Copy has a Book", or more meaningfully, something like "Subject has Student" (taking the famous aggregation example "Student **has a** Subject)?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Because this is can be implemented in any of those. If someone is capable with Java(it is my native language), then I can convert it back to C++, because this is just the way it handles

Comment: You can always go SQL way and create a class linking Book and Copy together. That's however is seldom useful in C++ programs.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Hi, you mean I need a database? I am not allowed to

Comment: No, I meant you could mimic database structure, because these classes look a lot like database objects. Also, noticing ^up - there are *a lot* of pretty famous people here. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Thanks for the reply. Could you please be kind enough to create a diagram, code or something like that? It would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: @Yohan sorry, but I'm quite fed up with my uni assignments lately. Judging from this diagram, though, you want to have a member `unique_ptr<Copy>` in Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we create a connection back, would that be like "Copy has a Book"

No, it wouldn't. A simple [dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_(UML)) relationship (e.g. a reference or non-owning pointer in C++) is not the "has a" or "owns a" relationship you'd get from the stronger associations of aggregation or composition. That sounds like what you want here.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. You mean something like " Book *bookPtr " (pointer to book) in "Copy" class?

Comment: @Yohan: Yes, give `Copy` a pointer or reference to its associated `Book`.