# Designing a communication system for a program that uses object aggregation

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, game-engine

I'm making a Component Based Game Engine, and I try to separate data from logic as much as possible by using this design:

```
                                      Engine
              /                          |                                \
     EntityManager            ComponentManager                         SystemManager
(vector of entities)      (map of (entities - vector of components)) (vector of systems)
```

Where essentially all these managers are just holders of Entities, Components, and Systems accordingly.

A brief description of these is:

Entity: A class that represents every object in the game (just and UUID).

Component : An abstract class that (its subclasses) will hold only data about a specific thing for an Entity,as an ex. PositionComponent will only have the x,y values of an Entity nothing more.

System: A abstract class that (its subclasses) will have all the logic to act on Enities,
ex. PositionSystem will have in its Process() method passed by the Engine an Entity to operate on, and change its component values using some predefined logic.

My problem is, how do I make objects communicate a senario like this?
For example how can I send a message from a System (that resides in the SystemManager) to the ComponentManager so I can get a specific component for the current Entity that the system is processing (I already have the methods in ComponentManagers to do this, thus my problem is what is the PROPER way design to do this)? Or generally a program that is modeled
like a Operating System (in layers from the inner kernel to the outer world) how can achieve communication between every layer? Are there any good design patterns that are useful for this purpose?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the thought that eventually this system would be distributed or do you intend for this to live on a single instance?

Comment: I would look at zeromq (specifically the inter process communication).  The advantage to designing this way is if you decide to distribute this program later you can do with with minimal changes.

Comment: I didn't get why SystemManager can't call ComponentManager directly to get the component? Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: Part of Object Orientation is to do with combining data and logic...

Comment: @TheArtist it depends on how do your iteraction looks like. Do you use event model/callbacks or you want to get data directly. In second case, why don't you just shift all responsibility to `Engine` class. `Engine` can hold all maps/collections of common usage. And when you want to pull something from one Manager you just kick your Engine like `engine.getComponent(currentSystem, currentComponent)` or something like that. I haven't got enough details to suggest something specific. Can you get code examples with brief comments what you want to improve?

Comment: If you ask 10 people how to do this properly you will get 10 answers.  Why are you trying to separate code from data?  What is the purpose?  You are going to need some form of reflection..  And having data and code separated means your going to need to reflect the data, then reflect the code..  Its twice as much work and prone to the types of errors that we hoped to eliminate by moving to OOA, and creating C++ in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing Connections within Aggregation classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505463/implementing-connections-within-aggregation-classes)

Comment: Do you want to see examples in C++ only, or are examples in other languages fine, to help give you an idea of how you can implement something like this? I wrote up a working example, but realized after the fact it was in C# and not C++

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do loosely coupled communication is messaging.
Essentially every component has an inbox and other components send messages to that inboxes.
You can also do things like broadcasting to groups etc.

You should keep in mind that a high level of abstraction can hit performance and in a game you need high performance.
So you should be careful with hot parts of your code, meaning parts that will be called very frequently,